# Passing and Returning StringBuilders: Java

Tags: java

I was referred to this site by a friend.  I like that I was able to look at some similar threads before I started this thread.  Unfortunately, I didn't see anything about this specific issue.

I'm having an issue passing StringBuilders from object to object in Java.  I don't know what the problem is and am lost.  I can pass and return data all day.  With StringBuilders, it just doesn't work.  I'm thinking it's something really easy that i'm simply too frustrated to see.

I have a homework assignment which asks me to declare 3 Stringbuilders with my first name, middle name, and last name.  No problem.

It also wants 3 objects to do different formats of the name.  The formatting portion is easy.  I can't figure out how to return the work back to the main.

Here's a snippet:

```
public class Builder
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder("John");
      StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder("Que");
      StringBuilder str3 = new StringBuilder("Doe");

      ???  = entireName(str1, str2, str3);
   }

  public static String entireName(StringBuilder s1, StringBuilder s2, StringBuilder s3)
  {
        System.out.print(s1);
        //insert.s1('4', ' ');//format stuff, not really necessary (not a problem).
        Ststem.out.print(s2);
        //etc..
        System.out.print(s3);
        return ????;
   }
}
```

the question marked stuff isn't filled in because nothing I put in there worked anyway.  I've tried declaring separate strings to pass back.  I've tried declaring the strings, then using those strings in the stringbuilder.  I've got nothing.  The formatting portion of this stuff is easy.  If I can't return to the main, it's wrong.

I really appreciate any help.  Thank you!

Comment: So the return value of the function should be "John Que Doe"?

Comment: Could you post the complete assignment? You state: "It also wants 3 objects to do different formats of the name". I would think this means you need to declare three new classes (at the very least ignoring inheritance/interfaces)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your prints are for debugging, you need s1.toString() and such

```
public static String entireName(StringBuilder s1, StringBuilder s2, StringBuilder s3)
  {
        System.out.print(s1.toString());
        //insert.s1('4', ' ');//format stuff, not necessary (not a problem)
        System.out.print(s2.toString());
        //etc..
        System.out.print(s3.toString());
        return s1.append(s2).append(s3).toString();
   }
```

I ran this, and it works:

```
public class Builder
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder("John");
      StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder("Que");
      StringBuilder str3 = new StringBuilder("Doe");

      String s = entireName(str1, str2, str3);

      System.out.println(s);
   }

   public static String entireName(StringBuilder s1, StringBuilder s2,
            StringBuilder s3)
   {
        // debugging removed
        return s1.append(s2).append(s3).toString();
   }

}
```

Comment: altho this modifies parameter 1 which you probably don't want to do, In my opinion you should never return a modified parameter. If you are going to modify a parameter, your should just have a void method. better would be to create a new StringBuilder append into it, and return that.

Comment: System.out.println(StringBuffer) works. Pass it any object and it basically does a toString on the object, then prints the results.

Comment: wow. Thanks a lot guys. Now I can finish up the other 3 objects. Yes, the print statements were to see if I was passing them into the object properly. I sincerely appreciate the help, and have the site bookmarked.  /bow